# Rails 4 status enum in concern - include only subset in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I have my status options in a concern, and I have many models that include that concern, but some models should be limited to a subset of all of the available statuses.

Is there a way to 'whitelist' or 'blacklist' the statuses that I have in the concern?

I would like to keep the actual integer for each status consistent across all models, in case we switch "status" from an enum to an ActiveModel - it will make that transition very easy.

**app/models/concerns/status_enum_concern.rb**

```
module StatusEnumsConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    enum status: [:active, :inactive, :sample, :staging, :sold_out, :expired, :wait_list]
    validates :status, presence:true

    def status_enum
      enum_array = []
      self.class.statuses.each { |v| enum_array << [v.first.titleize, v.second] }
      enum_array
    end
  end
end
```

**app/models/package.rb**

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  include StatusEnumsConcern
  # Any options here? 
  ...
end
```

Comment: What about create the basis list on the concern, but override it on the models (that need to extend the list or filter it).